# What are best ways to consolidate instance variables (to pass data from controller to the view) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, object, instance-variables

I have a details page in Rails 3 app that has several instance variable. For example, my view has the following instances:

```
@product
@program
@action
...etc...
```

Some of them are single strings, some are arrays (result of requests from external APIs). Overall, the data comes from at least 3 models.

My question is: What is the best way to consolidate instance variables so my view and my controller look cleaner (without sacrificing readability)? I understand the question is open-ended and everyone has their own preferences, but what are some of the options? I am thinking along the lines of combining the instance variables into an object so the previous code becomes something like this:

```
Details.product
Details.program
Details.action
```

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: Going the object route, is there any good examples (github, blog posts) of actually implementing it?

Comment: Use a hash or an object or don't bother. You'll have to have just as many object getters or hash key lookups as you would instance variables.

Comment: You are definitely right, it will be as many object getters any way I do it. I am looking at it fromt the usability / organization point of view. I am not a fan of going hash route, any good examples of going the object route then? (I will update the questions)

Comment: Presenter pattern might be what you are looking for: 
http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way to clean up your controller actions is to assign as few instance variables as possible there.  In practice, I try to only assign instance variables in the action/before_filters that are directly derived from the parameters passed to it.  Also, in general I try to push as many instance variable assignments to before_filters as I can so as to keep the actions slim.

But the best way to cut down on instance variable assignment in the actions is to use view helpers.  For instance if you are currently assigning an instance variable in an action which you use to output some div with, just use a view helper to do the output directly without any need to pass an object to the view.

Here's an example of a before_filter on a controller:

```
before_filter :assign_variables, :only => :show

def show; end

private
def assign_variables
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @program = Program.find(params[:program_id])
  @action = Action.find(params[:action_id])
end
```

Comment: I don't think I totally get what you are saying: on the model level, you set before filter to create certain instance variables based on the parameters that are being passed in (it is definitely not what you meant but this is my best interpretation). I do agree with view helpers, great options in some cases. Any examples of either approach on your github by any chance?

Comment: I added an example for the controller

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clear. It definitely works if I want to keep using the instance variables but make it cleaner to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using instance variables at all and go with the decent exposure gem instead.

https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure

http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure

Comment: Totally had no idea this existed, I will definitely check this out over the weekend.

Comment: Did you find decent exposure useful?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find yourself with several instance variables in a controller action, it best to use the presenter pattern.

This video explains everything in details 
["Ruby on Rails - Presenters & Decorators"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGdVJj-jNoc)